# QGIS: Heatmap of polutant data using contour polygons

Tags: qgis, error, contour, heat-map, smoothing

## 1. ASSIGNMENT

I have got an even grid of points (figure 1) with attributes of the values of emissions or pollutants caused by traffic - modelled in a specialised SW for this. I need to use this point layer to generate a graduated heatmap with a legend.

[image]
**Figure 1: Point layer**

### 1.1 Heatmap

A heatmap can easily be generated either by Kernel Density Estimation Heatmap or simply by selecting Heatmap in Layer `Properties > Symbology`. Such visualisation can be seen in figure 2. But such solution will not provide an option to create a legend that actually describes interesting data. This would mostly be for the purposes of visualising the more critical parts.

[image]
**Figure 2: Heatmap (symbology generated)**

### 1.2 Contour solution

I have decided to generate contours, using the polutant values as elevation data. Logically this should return good values. This attempt can be seen in figure 3.

[image]
**Figure 3: Heatmap generated as contours (pollutant values as elevation data)**

## 2. THE PROBLEM

At the first glance, the outputs don't exactly look good. This really needs some smoothing, but after this the polygons still need to be aligned. I tried the smoothing tool `Vector geometry > Smooth` but it doesn't do anything. The output is exactly the same, tried multiple settings (recommended values, extreme values, ...). To make it look professional, I really need to smooth it, is there any other way? I have seen recommendation of buffer and de-buffer (takes really really long and there is no guarantee the polygons will be aligned). I have a long-term problem with using GRASS extensions - I simply cannot and no-one here or anywhere was able to figure out why, possibly due to localization settings - unresolved - cannot use GRASS. If I first generate lines and smooth them and then generate polygons it is adding a lot of steps into the process that will make it difficult (I need to prepare a lot of different outputs - needing to repeat this about  36 times).

## 3. SUMMARY

**Is there a way to smooth the generated contours?**

Comment: Posting a bullet list of questions violates the One question per Question policy.

Comment: To answer Q1 + Q2 - try using the IDW or Krigging Interpolation, and generate your contours from there. You should post each question as a new question - it makes it easier to get the answer you need and keeps the post focussed. You can always link between questions.

Comment: Thank you all for additional info. I tried to use Krigin interpolation, but I have never worked with that, so maybe my setting were off, but the calculations for just one output would take several hours, maybe a day or two. This was not feasible so I had to do it the same way as before. Also I dont really know what IDW is. In the future, I would like to find a more optimized solution, so this question remains open.